# Find partial derivative in Utility Function (Econ)

Tags: r, derivative

I have the following function

```r
U<-function(A,b,t,alpha,g,beta){U<-A+(b*t^alpha)*(g^beta)}
```

and need to differentiate with respect to t.

Comment: You can get derivative symbolically: `Udt <-function(A,b,t,alpha,g,beta){ alpha * b * g^beta * t^(alpha - 1) }` and find values after that. Or you need numerical solution like [this](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/rmutil/html/runge.kutta.html)?

Comment: `Udt<-D(expression(A+(b*t^alpha)*(g^beta),"t"),"t")`?